# In SwiftUI, how to react to changes on "@Published vars" *outside* of a "View"

Tags: swiftui

Suppose I have the following `ObservableObject`, which generates a random String every second:

```
import SwiftUI

class SomeObservable: ObservableObject {

    @Published var information: String = ""

    init() {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(
            timeInterval: 1.0,
            target: self,
            selector: #selector(updateInformation),
            userInfo: nil,
            repeats: true
        ).fire()
    }

    @objc func updateInformation() {
        information = String("RANDOM_INFO".shuffled().prefix(5))
    }
}
```

And a `View`, which observes that:

```
struct SomeView: View {

    @ObservedObject var observable: SomeObservable

    var body: some View {
        Text(observable.information)
    }
}
```

The above will work as expected.
The `View` redraws itself when the `ObservableObject` changes:

[image: viewUpdate]

### **Now for the question**:

How could I do the same (say calling a function) in a "pure" `struct` that also observes the same `ObservableObject`? By "pure" I mean something that **does not** conform to `View`:

```
struct SomeStruct {

    @ObservedObject var observable: SomeObservable

    // How to call this function when "observable" changes?
    func doSomethingWhenObservableChanges() {
        print("Triggered!")
    }
}
```

(It could also be a `class`, as long as it's able to react to the changes on  the observable.)

It seems to be conceptually very easy, but I'm  clearly missing something.

(Note: I'm using Xcode 11, beta 6.)

---

### Update (for future readers) (paste in a Playground)

Here is a possible solution, based on the awesome answer provided by @Fabian:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import PlaygroundSupport

class SomeObservable: ObservableObject {

    @Published var information: String = "" // Will be automagically consumed by `Views`.

    let updatePublisher = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>() // Can be consumed by other classes / objects.

    // Added here only to test the whole thing.
    var someObserverClass: SomeObserverClass?

    init() {
        // Randomly change the information each second.
        Timer.scheduledTimer(
            timeInterval: 1.0,
            target: self,
            selector: #selector(updateInformation),
            userInfo: nil,
            repeats: true
        ).fire()    }

    @objc func updateInformation() {
        // For testing purposes only.
        if someObserverClass == nil { someObserverClass = SomeObserverClass(observable: self) }

        // `Views` will detect this right away.
        information = String("RANDOM_INFO".shuffled().prefix(5))

        // "Manually" sending updates, so other classes / objects can be notified.
        updatePublisher.send()
    }
}

class SomeObserverClass {

    @ObservedObject var observable: SomeObservable

    // More on AnyCancellable on: apple-reference-documentation://hs-NDfw7su
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

    init(observable: SomeObservable) {
        self.observable = observable

        // `sink`: Attaches a subscriber with closure-based behavior.
        cancellable = observable.updatePublisher
            .print() // Prints all publishing events.
            .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] _ in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.doSomethingWhenObservableChanges()
        })
    }

    func doSomethingWhenObservableChanges() {
        print(observable.information)
    }
}

let observable = SomeObservable()

struct SomeObserverView: View {
    @ObservedObject var observable: SomeObservable
    var body: some View {
        Text(observable.information)
    }
}
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(SomeObserverView(observable: observable))
```

> Result

[image: result]

(Note: it's necessary to run the app in order to check the console output.)

Comment: Does it have to be a struct?

Comment: Not necessarily. It could be a class. I'll  update the question.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The old way was to use callbacks which you registered. The newer method is to use the `Combine` framework to create publishers for which you can registers further processing, or in this case a `sink` which gets called every time the `source publisher` sends a message. The publisher here sends nothing and so is of type `<Void, Never>`.

#### Timer publisher

To get a publisher from a timer can be done directly through `Combine` or creating a generic publisher through `PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()`, registering for messages and sending them in the `timer-callback` via `publisher.send()`. The example has both variants.

#### ObjectWillChange Publisher

Every `ObservableObject` does have an `.objectWillChange` publisher for which you can register a `sink` the same as you do for `Timer publishers`. It should get called every time you call it or every time a `@Published` variable changes. Note however, that is being called before, and not after the change. (`DispatchQueue.main.async{}` inside the sink to react after the change is complete).

#### Registering

Every sink call creates an `AnyCancellable` which has to be stored, usually in the object with the same lifetime the `sink` should have. Once the cancellable is deconstructed (or `.cancel()` on it is called) the `sink` does not get called again.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ReceiveOutsideView: View {
    #if swift(>=5.3)
        @StateObject var observable: SomeObservable = SomeObservable()
    #else
        @ObservedObject var observable: SomeObservable = SomeObservable()
    #endif

    var body: some View {
        Text(observable.information)
            .onReceive(observable.publisher) {
                print("Updated from Timer.publish")
        }
        .onReceive(observable.updatePublisher) {
            print("Updated from updateInformation()")
        }
    }
}

class SomeObservable: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var information: String = ""
    
    var publisher: AnyPublisher<Void, Never>! = nil
    
    init() {
        
        publisher = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: RunLoop.main, in: .common).autoconnect().map{_ in
            print("Updating information")
            //self.information = String("RANDOM_INFO".shuffled().prefix(5))
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        
        Timer.scheduledTimer(
            timeInterval: 1.0,
            target: self,
            selector: #selector(updateInformation),
            userInfo: nil,
            repeats: true
        ).fire()
    }
    
    let updatePublisher = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    
    @objc func updateInformation() {
        information = String("RANDOM_INFO".shuffled().prefix(5))
        updatePublisher.send()
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    
    @ObservedObject var observable: SomeObservable
    
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    init(observable: SomeObservable) {
        self.observable = observable
        
        cancellable = observable.publisher.sink{ [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else {
                return
            }
            
            self.doSomethingWhenObservableChanges() // Must be a class to access self here.
        }
    }
    
    // How to call this function when "observable" changes?
    func doSomethingWhenObservableChanges() {
        print("Triggered!")
    }
}
```

Note here that if no sink or receiver at the end of the pipeline is registered, the value will be lost. For example creating `PassthroughSubject<T, Never>`, immediately sending a value and aftererwards returning the publisher makes the messages sent get lost, despite you registering a sink on that subject afterwards. The usual workaround is to wrap the subject creation and message sending inside a `Deferred {}` block, which only creates everything within, once a sink got registered.

A commenter notes that `ReceiveOutsideView.observable` is owned by `ReceiveOutsideView`, because observable is created inside and directly assigned. On reinitialization a new instance of `observable` will be created. This can be prevented by use of `@StateObject` instead of `@ObservableObject` in this instance.

Comment: It's a little more complex than I thought -- but you nailed it. I updated my question with a working example, based on your answer. Thanks for your time and explanation, which also includes the `Timer publisher`... Very useful. 

Comment: It is more important if it is possible to update a @Published value outside a View - from a regular code. Say I'm reading a value from DB and want this value to be updated in a View.

Comment: That is what `ObservableObject` is made for so yes. `Published` is only special in that it calls `objectWillChange` at the right time. Any views using values from the `ObservableObject` should get reevaluated (my best guess).

Comment: Note, that with the introduction of @StateObject ReceiveOutsideView should have it's observable property as a StateObject rather than an ObservableObject because it owns / holds the instance.

Comment: @lenny good point, I updated the answer. Though StateObject is  >=5.3 so not everyone will be able to use it yet, but definitely in the future.

Comment: @backslash-f. I just found this post because I have a similar issue. I tried the solution mentioned in your post (Fabian), but in my case I have a SomeObserverStruct (A View) instead of SomeObserverClass and that brings problem with "Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter" in the .sink as soon as I want to do something useful with some data (not only print "HELLO=WORLD"). Do you have any tip? I must admit I have no experience with Combine so I may be doing something wrong.

Comment: @Michel I'm not clear what you are trying to do, however with conjecture: I assume you try to initialize the sink inside a struct function or initializer, where you want to modify or use (reference) the struct itself (self), but the struct lifecycle is independent of the class. The struct might be dead and recreated until the sink is executed, as happens very often with view-structs. Thats I think why the compiler forbids you to reference self there. Maybe you could split your logic and data from the view into a class and use the view only for presenting? Maybe worth a new question.